# ClassCastException while typecasting

Tags: inheritance, parent-child, classcastexception

I know this seems to be simple, but I wanted to know the deepen reason behind this.

I have the below code for which got a ClassCastException

```
Parent parent = newParent();
Child child = (Child)parent;   //ClassCastException: 
                               Parent cannot be cast to Child.
```

I have modified the same with the below code and got executed successfully.

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child = new Child();
parent = child;
System.out.println(parent.color); 
child=(Child)parent; 
System.out.println(child.color);

**output:** 
       Parent_color
       Child_color
```

I just want to know what made the main difference to distinguish the results here? and how it could be justified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downcasting is allowed in Java if there is a possibility that it succeeds at run time.

Child child = (Child)parent;

Compiler will allow this, because at run time "parent" might refer to an instance of "Child". But its failing at run time, because "parent" is not referring to an instance of "Child" , its referring to an instance of "Parent" instead.

Let's see what would happen if there were no ClassCastException :

Suppose you have defined your classes as follows:

```
class Parent {

void aMethod(){
}

}

class Child {

void bMethod(){
}

}
```

And suppose we have these statements defined,

```
1. Parent parent = new Parent();
2. Child child = (Child)parent;
3. child.bMethod();// we should be able to do this, because there should not be any issue executing methods defined in "Child" type with a reference variable of "Child" type.
```

But the last line is illegal, because there is no method named "bMethod" exists in our Parent class and we are trying to execute a method which does not even exists. Hope this justifies the "ClassCastException".

Now, lets examine the modified code of yours:

```
   1. Parent parent = new Parent();
   2  Child child = new Child();
   3. parent = child;
   4. System.out.println(parent.color); 
   5. child=(Child)parent; 
   6. System.out.println(child.color);
```

Here the casting

```
child=(Child)parent; // works as you expected, parent is now referring to an instance of "Child" according to the assignment "parent = child" at line no 3.
```

is working fine because "parent" is now referring to an instance of "Child" class. So, the "child" reference variable is now referring to an instance of "Child" only and the run time environment is happy with this.